# get all tables (classes) from realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, realm

I'm using Realm.io as database and I need a `select * from all_tables` in Realm.
I mean a method returning an RLMArray, but I have not found anything about this.

I need the class reference, such as Realm Browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[realm.schema.objectSchema valueForKey:@"className"]` to get an `NSArray` of all of the `RLMObject` subclasses used in the Realm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible at the moment. You should request it on github. In the mean time you will have to create your own. First you have to know that an RLMArray can only hold one type so if in these different tables there are different types than you can not do the following. It would be as easy as creating your own method for this. It would consist of getting all objects from each table and just inserting them into the RLMArray; If your tables don't have the same type then you will have to use a NSMutableArray or an NSArray.